# php post key is json string

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I'am sending the request using

```js
function loadData(interfaceName) {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<?= (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https' : 'http') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>',
        data: {
            interface: interfaceName,
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        document.getElementById('statistics').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    });
}
```

and receiving in php using

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    dd($_POST);
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
```

but php is returns this:

[image: output]

how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved when i used axios like this:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('interface', interfaceName);

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '<?= (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https' : 'http') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>',
    data: params,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
})
```